# Combine variables in SQL Server XPath expression

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xpath

I have this expression on SQL Server which works fine:

```
xmlData.value('sum(//*[variable1="222"]/./variable3)', 'float')
```

I want to rewrite it so it contains these three variables:

```
declare @var1 nvarchar(max) = 'variable1'
declare @var2 int = 222
declare @var3 nvarchar(max) = 'variable3'
```

Here's some xml relevant to my question:

```
<main>
  <TAL>
    <variable1>222</variable1>
    <Name>someName1</Name>
    <a>2</a>
    <b>73</b>
    <variable3>1</variable3>
  </TAL>
  <TAL>
    <variable1>333</variable1>
    <Name>someName2</Name>
    <a>4</a>
    <b>56</b>
    <variable3>2</variable3>
  </TAL>
</main>
```

I have tried several options such as:

```
xmlData.value('sum(//*[local-name()=sql:variable("@var1")="local-name()=sql:variable("@var2")"]/./local-name()=sql:variable("@var3"))', 'float')
```

but no success. What would be the proper way to write the XPath expression using variables?

Comment: Hi livnt, can you explain in words what it is you are trying to achieve? I can't really make out what the sample xpath query you have in your question is trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks TT, I'm searching an element named "variable1" and its value. If it's 222, I'm getting the sibling of it - element "variable3" value. Problem is that I need to pass the variables as parameters to a function, so the expression needs to contain them

Comment: Hi again livnt. Typically for questions like these, it is handy to include some sample XML for people to toy around with, and the expected result for your sample XPath query for verification purposes. Makes it that much easier for people around here to start with actually answering your question. It is always possible the edit your question to include such a sample, using the `edit` link underneath the question.

Comment: As per your suggestion, the question is now contains some xml of mine. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because we're moving paths into node tests, we'll have to rearrange things a bit. Queries like these lack the convenience of static paths, unfortunately.

```
select xmlData.value('
    sum(
        //*[local-name()=sql:variable("@var1") and data(.)=sql:variable("@var2")]
            /parent::*/*[local-name()=sql:variable("@var3")]
    )', 'float')
```

Comment: Jeroen, its working! This is exactly what I needed.  Thanks a lot!

Comment: @livnt Just a tiny hint: instead of `data(.)` I'd use `(text()[1] cast as xs:int?)` which will enable the comparisson as int-values and you can use `/../` instead of `/parent::*/` - but that's more a matter of taste...